# Where have I gone wrong on this code

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to send form details to multiple email address with this code, it is not working, can anyone teach me where I have gone wrong please. My last question was marked as duplicate but it did not answer my question, please help me with this. It is not sending to any of the email addresses when run.

```
    <?php

$EmailFrom = "WelcomeToFarla,";
$EmailTo = array('prospects@farla.co.uk' , 'gezzietremors@hotmail.com' , 'prospects@farla.co.uk'); 
$Subject = "Online Form Submission";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 

// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
  exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email 
$success = ($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=index.html\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=index.html\">";
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to convert that array to string ($EmailTo).

Comment: Hi Nevermind, thanks for the reply, I thought id tried that but it did not work and im lost on how to adjust this script

Comment: You're not saying what isn't working. Do none of the addresses work? Some? All, but not consistently? What debugging have you done? Have you tried using one address, instead of an array? Does that work?

Comment: Did you tried with this function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php ?

Comment: Hi Andrewsi, it is not sending to any of the emails

Comment: Nevermind - No I havent, is there any chance you can guide me on how to use this within my script above please ?

Comment: $list=implode(",",$EmailTo); $success = ($list, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>"); If it doesn't work - problem is somewhere else....

Comment: you're not calling the mail() function - see the answer provided below

Answer (score 3):

Unless your code was accidentally truncated, you're not actually calling the mail function. This:

```
// send email 
$success = ($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");
```

should be this:

```
// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");
```